# While no funciona

Tags: javascript

Lo que me gustaría hacer es un while, donde previamente me pida que indique un nombre que está incluido en una array, y que finalmente me muestre la posición de la array donde está el nombre introducido.

El código es el siguiente:

```js
<script>


var Amigos = newArray ("EVA", "DIANA", "MARIO", "LOLI", "GHEORGHE", "LUCIA");
var Ultimo = Amigos.length;
var Posicion = 0;


var Vbusca=prompt("Introduce el nombre");


while(Amigos[Posicion] != Vbusca && Posicion<Ultimo ){
 Posicion++;
}

if(Amigos[Posicion]==Vbusca){
 alert("La posición donde se encuentra " + Vbusca + "es la posición: " + Posicion);
}

else {
   alert("El nombre que buscas no está en la lista");
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El new array lo tienes mal, lo has escrito junto.

Otra manera de hacerlo:
Puedes declarar un array directamente poniendo los valores entre corchetes.

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
```

[ARRAYs JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)

```js
var Amigos = ["EVA", "DIANA", "MARIO", "LOLI", "GHEORGHE", "LUCIA"];
console.log("Array: "+Amigos);
var Ultimo = Amigos.length;
var Posicion = 0;

var Vbusca=prompt("Introduce el nombre");
console.log("Escrito: "+Vbusca);

while(Amigos[Posicion] != Vbusca && Posicion<Ultimo ){
 Posicion++;
}

console.log("Escrito: "+Posicion);

if(Amigos[Posicion]==Vbusca){
 alert("La posición donde se encuentra " + Vbusca + "es la posición: " + Posicion);
}

else {
   alert("El nombre que buscas no está en la lista");
}
```

Comment: No tiene mal el `new Array` lo único es que lo dejó pegado